# How can I Set Validation.ErrorTemplate in Code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, passwordbox

I've been looking in StackOverflow, and several questions are done. But they don't work.

I have this `PasswordBox`:

```
<PasswordBox Width="160"
      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
      Margin="10,3"
      Name="textBoxUserPass"
      local:PasswordBoxAssistant.BindPassword="True"
      local:PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=Password, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, 
      ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
      Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" />
```

I first set the `ValidationErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"` so first time I load the `PasswordBox` it doesn't try to validate the box.

When I find a error, I try to change the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` so it shows a red border (as the `ErrorTemplate` I have defined) like this:

```
BindingExpression bePassword = textBoxUserPass.GetBindingExpression(PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword);
if (bePassword != null)
{
    bePassword.UpdateSource();
    if (bePassword.HasError)
    {
        var validationError = new ValidationError(new ExceptionValidationRule(), bePassword);
        Validation.MarkInvalid(bePassword, validationError);
        validationError.ErrorContent = Cultures.Resources.MessageNoPassword;
        var b = Resources["validationTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
        Validation.SetErrorTemplate(textBoxUserPass, b);
        }
    }
}
```

Where I have defined my **validationTemplate** on a `ResourceDictionary.xaml` like this:

```
    <Style x:Key="validationTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                    Foreground="Red"
                    FontSize="12pt">
                    *
                    </TextBlock>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                    </Border>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

A regular box, as you can see.

My problem comes **when trying to find this resource** to change my `Validation.ErrorTemplate` in code behind. I put a breakpoint, and this line:

```
var b = FindResource("validationTemplate") as ControlTemplate;
```

says that **b** is null. How I can find `"validationTemplate"` and use it??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your validationTemplate is a `Style` with a `Template`. Try `Template` only instead:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
        Foreground="Red"
        FontSize="12pt">
        *
        </TextBlock>
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Actually I solved it with this line:
var template = FindResource("validationTemplate") as ControlTemplate;
                    Validation.SetErrorTemplate(textBoxUserPass, template);

Comment: Then `FindResource` seems to be smarter then I thought because it's doing the cast for you.

Comment: But without your comment I wouldn't solved my problem, so I think it's  you who solved my problem. I will mark your answer as the good one and edit my post to fit for future users ;)